# Add fields to hr.employees

Tags: python, xml, inheritance, odoo, odoo-10

Trying to add fields to the model hr.employees (**cmp** after **address_home_id**)

This is my code.

**__manifest__.py**

```
'name': 'Add Fields to HR module',
'description': 'Add Fields to HR Module',
'depends': ['base','hr'],
'data':[
  'views/res_hr_view.xml',  
],
```

**res_hr.py**

```
 from odoo import models, fields, api 
 class ResHR(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr'
    cmp = fields.Char()
```

**res_hr_view.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <odoo>
    <record id="res_hr_form_inherited"   
     model="ir.ui.view"> 
     <field name="name">Add Fields HR Employees</field> 
     <field name="model">hr.employee</field> 
     <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/> 
     <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
     <field name="address_home_id" position="after"> 
       <field name="cmp" string="C.M.P"/>
       </field>
    </field>
   </record>
```

but show  me te next  error when I try to install  it.

```
   Field 'cmp' does not exist error on inherited view.
   > /home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/models.py(1083)_validate_fields()
   -> raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating 
   constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think you mean `_inherit='hr.employee'`

Comment: Hi @yorodm, it's correct must be 'hr.employee'  I made the change but I get the same error.

Comment: Have you restarted Odoo after changing a *py file? If not, do it. If the error persists, please copy and paste the log from about 5 lines before the first ERROR message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your res_hr.py is imported. Normally a module/app looks like

```
models/
|-- __init__.py
|-- model1.py
|-- model2.py
views/
|-- model1_views.xml
|-- model2_views.xml
__init__.py
__manifest__.py
```

The `__init__.py` should import `models` and the `models/__init__.py` should import `model1` and `model2`. Restart the server when ready for module installation/update or use the dev-mode to let Odoo handle it itself.

Comment: Thank you @CZoellner  !!  it was that